# Can't get Mongodb running

Tags: macos, mongodb, installation

I've just installed Mongodb by following the instructions on the link below.

Everything went fine and no errors. However, when trying to run Mongodb (by typing 'Mongod' or 'Mongo') I get the following error: mongod: command not found. What can be wrong?

I have tried to install it once again but I get a message that it's already installed.

The [Instructions](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+OS+X) that I followed (Mac OSX).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a PATH issue to me.  The installation on Mac OSX may not automatically add MongoDB to the system PATH (a list of programs that can be run from any directory).

Check out the comment below in that article `m o l a r o`'s comment refers to specific PATH issues in Mac OSX http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+OS+X#comment-78182225.

Answer (score 6):

Did you add the folder where *mongod* resides in to the path?

Try to cd into the folder and execute mongod directly with

```
./mongod
```